# How to nest an array in python based on number size?

Tags: python, nested

Having trouble creating a nesting algorithm to go from ex: `[3,4,5,5,5,4]` to `[3,[4,[5,5,5],4]`].

- If the number is greater than the previous, it should be nested at a deeper level.
- If the number is the same, it should be at the same level.

```
def nest_list(lst):
    stack = []
    for num in lst:
        if not stack or num > stack[-1][0]:
            stack.append([num])
        elif num == stack[-1][0]:
            stack[-1].append(num)
        else:
            temp = stack.pop()
            while stack and num <= stack[-1][0]:
                temp = [stack.pop()[0], temp]
            stack.append([num, temp])
    while len(stack) > 1:
        temp = stack.pop()
        stack[-1].append(temp)
    return stack[0]
```

Comment: And how, *specifically*, does your posted code differ from what you want?

Comment: What should `[1,2,2,4,3,2,1]` produce?

Comment: @ScottHunter probably `[1,[2,2,[4],[3]],2],1]`

Comment: @TheBlckbird: *Probably*?  Based on what?  Why not `[1,[2,2,[4],3],2,1]`?

Comment: @ScottHunter because 3 and 2 are not the same number so they don’t belong into the same "layer"

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest recursion for this.

When the second position is larger than the first, find the nearest subsequent position with a value less or equal to the first and recursively nest that sublist, then concatenate nesting of the remainder of the list.

```
def nest(L):
    if len(L) < 2: return L
    if L[0]>=L[1]:
        return L[:1] + nest(L[1:])
    i = next((i for i,n in enumerate(L[1:],1) if n<=L[0]),len(L))
    return L[:1]+[*filter(None,[nest(L[1:i])])]+nest(L[i:])
```

output:

```
A = [3,4,5,5,5,4]
print(nest(A))
[3, [4, [5, 5, 5], 4]]

B = [1,2,3,1,5,4,1,6]
print(nest(B))
[1, [2, [3]], 1, [5, 4], 1, [6]]              

C = [1,2,2,4,3,2,1]
print(nest(C))
[1, [2, 2, [4, 3], 2], 1]    

D = [2,3,4,3,1,1]
print(nest(D))
[2, [3, [4], 3], 1, 1]
```

**[EDIT] Different interpretation**

If your numbers represent depth levels, then decreasing sequences should also cause nesting.  In that case, you could leverage the groupby function from itertools:

```
from itertools import groupby
def nest(L,level=0):
    level = max(level, min(L))
    return [ r for n,(*g,) in groupby(L,key=lambda n:n==level)
               for r in (g if n else [nest(g,level+1)]) ]
```

*Note that `level = max(level, min(L))` is only there to avoid intermediate nesting levels.  If you do want the intermediate nesting levels, remove that line so that `[1,3,1]` results in `[1,[[3]],1]` instead of `[1,[3],1]`*

```
A = [3,4,5,5,5,4]
print(nest(A))
[3, [4, [5, 5, 5], 4]]

B = [1,2,3,1,5,4,1,6]
print(nest(B))
[1, [2, [3]], 1, [[5], 4], 1, [6]]             

C = [1,2,2,4,3,2,1]
print(nest(C))
[1, [2, 2, [[4], 3], 2], 1]    

D = [2,3,4,3,1,1]
print(nest(D))
[[2, [3, [4], 3]], 1, 1]
```

Comment: B has 4 & 5 at the same level.  C has both 3 & 4 at the same level.  D has both 2's and 1's at the top level.

Comment: That is based on the OP's statement that "If the number is greater than the previous, it should be nested".  What to do for decreasing a sequence is not defined so your guess is as good as mine.  Perhaps it's not even a condition that exists in the input data.